# patch mattimepicker in angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular5, angular8

I have an angular mattimepicker. I am using it in a reactive form. I am finding it difficult to patch the value to the edit form

```
    <h1>Reactive Form</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Time</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="time" matTimepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

"1:32 PM" This is the value I am trying to patch it to the above formfield
Kindly help if you guys know

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-timepicker-current-time-3ns5r1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: @Tejeshree just take this value "1:32 PM" and show me how to patch it or seetvalue it on the mattimepicker on that stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this on your `ngOnInit()` your matdatepicker will have a default value of `1:32`

```
newTime = {
    hour: null,
    min: null,
    timeclock: null
}
assume_backendTime = '1:32 AM';

ngOnInit() {
  /* extracting the time only | 1:32 PM = 1:32 */
  let timeOnly = this.assume_backendTime.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
  /* extracting the AM/PM | 1:32 PM = PM */
  this.newTime.timeclock = this.assume_backendTime.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
  /* separating the hour:minute separated by : into array  */
  let timeArry = this.assume_backendTime.split(/[ :]+/);
  this.newTime.hour = timeArry[0];
  this.newTime.min = timeArry[1];
  console.log(this.newTime)
  let patchTime = new Date()
  patchTime.setHours(this.newTime.hour, this.newTime.min);
  this.form.controls['time'].patchValue(patchTime);
}
```

see stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-timepicker-current-time-glnur8

Comment: Is there any way where I can store this "1:32 AM" value in a variable and directly patch that in my formcontrol instead of setting hours? @Stacks Queue. I am asking this because I am getting the value  as "1:32 AM" from the backend

Comment: your value from the backend is **hours:minutes** only? no other dates? also the time is string and noted as PM and AM? or would it be **13:32** if PM

Comment: yea its from hours and minutes. I give that value to the backend in the first place using this picker in stackblitz.  yea it comes with AM and PM  @Stacks Queue

Comment: DO U WANT ME TO SEND THE VALUE IN A DIFF FORMAT TO THE BACKEND TO HELP THIS CASE? @Stacks Queue

Comment: It would always come as AM and PM format. It wont be in 13:32PM

Comment: Well it is easier to parse if you send the value in **24-hour** clock format eg. instead of **1:32 PM** you will just have to send **13:32** no more AM/PM included. But I think we could still do that in AM/PM. Give me time to edit the stackblitz

Comment: I edited the answer for you. you also check on stack blitz

Comment: I did check but if its "6:32PM" it has to go sit as 18:32 pm in that timepicker UI

Comment: you can add `mode='12h'` this will change your matpicker into `12-hour format` also it will have am/pm please check again the stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you want. You will have to use `moment`

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const input = '1:32AM';
    const momentDate = moment(input, ["h:mm A"]).toDate();
    this.form.patchValue({ time: momentDate });
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-timepicker-current-time-jt6zwd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can try changing input values to test your use case. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Take any random date and set its value to time formControlName
Your ts file will look like:-

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  form = new FormGroup({
    time: new FormControl()
  });
  ngOnInit() {
   const event = new Date('May 30,  01:32:30');
    this.form.patchValue({ time:event });
  }
}
```